# In awk, what is the meaning of getline < "-"

Tags: awk

```
BEGIN {
   printf "Enter your name"
   getline < "-"
}
```

Above: why not just `getline` instead of `getline < "-"`? what does `"-"` mean?

Comment: This question is completely unreadable. I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: Where is the question ?

Answer (score 2):

`-` means *standard input*, such as the terminal.  Without that, if a file is specified on the command line, awk will read from that file.

To start, let's assume was have a file:

```
$ cat file
Tom
```

Now, let's run your code without the `<"-"`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf "Enter your name: "; getline; print "Name=" $0 }' file
Enter your name: Name=Tom
```

As you can see, it read the name from the file `file`.

Suppose instead that we want the user to enter a name at the terminal.  In this case, we want to get a line from the terminal, denoted `-`, not from the file.  Thus, we use:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { printf "Enter your name: "; getline <"-"; print "Name=" $0 }' file
Enter your name: John
Name=John
```

As you can see, this one read the name that I entered at the terminal and ignored the file.

Answer (score 2):

That snippet is part of an awk program. Awk is not a shell.

```
getline < "-"
```

reads a line from standard input.

```
getline
```

reads a line from the first file specified on the `awk` command line, or standard input if there is no command-line arguments.

So they will do the same thing if you don't specify a file on the `awk` command-line, but if you do specify a file, `getline < "-"` will still read from stdin.